# Implement Quartz for Cron Scheduling with Spring Scheduler

Tags: spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

```
@Component
public class QuartzConfig implements Job{

    @Autowired
    private JobService jobService;

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {

        System.out.println("Check Status");
        jobService.checkQueueStatus();
    }
```

In quartz.properties file I have added this detail:

```
# thread-pool
org.quartz.threadPool.class=org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=2
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread=true

# job-store
# Enable this property for RAMJobStore
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
```

How can I give the details about the job and trigger for Cron Scheduling?
Please help with the detailed flow.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of examples on the web showing you how to integrate Quartz and Spring. You may want to check one of our test web apps available on GitHub:

https://github.com/quartzdesk/quartzdesk-test-webapps/blob/master/quartzdesk-test-quartz-v2-4-x/quartzdesk-test-quartz-v2-4-x-logback/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml

Search for "quartzScheduler" to find the Quartz scheduler bean and then scroll down to see  jobDetails and triggers attributes.